# Не понимаю где я ошибся в задании на HashMap

Tags: java, java-hashmap, методы

Написал код, вроде рабочий, но не принимает проверка JavaRush, в итоге переделал элегантно и правильно, но не могу понять ГДЕ ошибка. Вроде же всё должно работать. Понимаю, что подход у меня, кхм, интересный, но по моему мнению он должен работать.

Задача такая:

1. в методе `СreateMap` создать `HashMap<String, String>`
2. в методе `removeTheFirstNameDuplicates` провести поиск и удаление совпадающих значений
3. используя метод `removeItemFromMapByValue` (он уже был готов согласно условию задачи)

Ошибку IntelliJ Idea не выдаёт, вроде всё работает, но валидатор JavaRush не принимает (просто Ваша задача не прошла тестирование). Я подозреваю два варианта - либо я молодец, а валидатор нет. Либо я по неопытности что-то сделал не так.

```
public static HashMap<String, String> createMap() {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("К1", "И1");
    map.put("К2", "И2");
    map.put("К3", "И3");
    map.put("К4", "И4");
    map.put("К5", "И5");
    map.put("К6", "И1");
    map.put("К7", "И7");
    map.put("К8", "И8");
    map.put("К9", "И9");
    map.put("К10", "И10");
    return map;

}

public static void removeTheFirstNameDuplicates(HashMap<String, String> map) {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> iter = map.entrySet().iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String, String> pair = iter.next();
        list.add(pair.getValue());
    }
    HashMap<String, String> copy = new HashMap<>(map);
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> it2 = copy.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it2.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String, String> pair2 = it2.next();
        String smap = pair2.getValue();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            String sarr = list.get(i);
            if (smap.equals(sarr)) {
                removeItemFromMapByValue(map, smap);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void removeItemFromMapByValue(HashMap<String, String> map, String value) {
    HashMap<String, String> copy = new HashMap<String, String>(map);
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> pair : copy.entrySet()) {
        if (pair.getValue().equals(value))
            map.remove(pair.getKey());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {}
```

Comment: какая именно ошибка? и добавьте как звучит задание.

Comment: добавил в вопрос недостающие данные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В результате такой итерации вы удалите вообще все вхождения в map:

На этом этапе вы заполняете список значениями из мапы

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> iter = map.entrySet().iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<String, String> pair = iter.next();
    list.add(pair.getValue());
}
```

При этом список будет содержать все значения (включая и просто значения, и дубликаты) и почти эквивалентен результата простого вызова `.values()`.

В следующем участке кода вы удаляете из мапы все значения, которые есть в списке

```
HashMap<String, String> copy = new HashMap<>(map);
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> it2 = copy.entrySet().iterator();
while (it2.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<String, String> pair2 = it2.next();
    String smap = pair2.getValue();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        String sarr = list.get(i);
        if (smap.equals(sarr)) {
            removeItemFromMapByValue(map, smap);
        }
    }
}
```

Так как в список уже загнаны вообще все значения, мапа очистится целиком.

Ваша настоящая задача - найти все дубликаты, сформировать из них коллекцию, после чего удалить каждый элемент из этой коллекции. Это делается довольно просто с помощью любой реализации Set, при желании можно осуществить вручную итерацией над списком.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, понял ошибку. Задание я всё же решил (с помощью Set), но не мог понять что же не так в первом варианте решения.